# Proving that the given integral operator is injective

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

We are given the following: 
Let $ k \in C([a,b] \times ([a,b])$ Say $ \, k \not\equiv 0 .\, $ Let $ A: L^2 [a,b] \rightarrow L^2 [a,b] $
be defined as $ Ax(s) = \int_{a}^{b} k(s,t)x(t) \, d\mu(t), $ where $ x \in L^2 [a,b] $ (We are working with real valued functions here), and $ s \in [a,b] $. 
Now, we have to show that $A$ is an injective linear operator.

Further, prove that the range of A, $R(A)$ with the inner product defined by  $ \langle f, g \rangle  =  \langle A^{-1}f, A^{-1}g \rangle $ where, $f$ and $g$ belong to $R(A)$) is a Hilbert space.

My attempt is as follows:

I could show that the given operator is linear - It just follows from the properties of the Lebesgue integral.
Now, I have to show that it is injective.

i.e. if $\hspace{2mm}  x_1, x_2 \in L^2 [a,b]$ are such that $Ax_1 = Ax_2 $, then, need to show that $x_1 = x_2.$

i.e. I need to show that if $\int_{a}^{b} k(s,t) \, (x_1(t) - x_2(t)) \, d\mu(t) = 0$, then, $ x_1(t) = x_2(t) .$

I thought of using integration by parts, but, my functions need not be differentiable here.
Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: This need not be true in general. Consider $k\equiv 0$, for instance.

Comment: Let us say when $k \neq 0$. Let me edit the question.

Comment: $k \neq 0$ doesn't save you. Any kernel of the form $k(s,t) = f(s)g(t)$ generates a rank one operator, which is never injective.

Comment: @Klaus could you be more specific? I didn't quite understand you

Comment: If $A$ is injective, then $A$ has an inverse on its image. If that inverse could be well defined, then $A$ is injective, but can you intuitively think about what the inverse would be?

Comment: @AdithyaS If $k(s,t)$ is of the form $f(s)g(t)$, then $Ax(s)$ is always a scalar multiple of $f(s)$. Hence the range of $A$ is one-dimensional and the operator can't be injective. This thus provides a lot more counterexamples than just $k = 0$.

Comment: I would double check the statement of the question because the given integral operator is not Fredholm.

Comment: @Ruy I have updated the question. Kindly check

Comment: @AdithyaS You only changed the question insignificantly. The statement you want to prove is still wrong for the same reasons.

Comment: I see that you have changed "$dx$" to "$d\mu(x)$" but this does not make your operator Fredholm.  Perhaps you should just delete the word "Fredhom" from the title, but in case there is a reason for it to be there, it makes me think the definition of the operator is incorrect.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I can't think of any inverse intuitively.

Comment: I don't think the question is false, as they further ask me to prove that the range of A, $R(A)$ with the inner product defined by  $ \langle f, g \rangle  =  \langle A^{-1}f, A^{-1}g \rangle $ (where, $f$ and $g$ belong to $R(A)$) is a Hilbert space.

Comment: @AdithyaS Do you know a (explicit) basis for $L^2[a,b]$? By explicit, I mean there exists a basis is obvious, but can you write down the functions?

Comment: @AdithyaS As you insist that the question is posed correctly, I'll give you a simpler counterexample. Consider the kernel $k(s,t) = 1$. Then $Ax(s) = \int_a^b x(t) \, \mathrm{d}\mu(t)$ for all $s$. Now take any function $x \neq 0$ that satisfies  $\int_a^b x(t) \, \mathrm{d}\mu(t) = 0$ (such a function exists unless your $L^2$-space only consists of constants). Thus $Ax = 0$ and $A$ is not injective.

Comment: @Klaus this makes sense and you're right. thanks.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I know that the trigonometric system $ \{ e^{2 \pi i n x} \}$  is an orthonormal basis for $ L^2 [0, 1]$

Comment: @Klaus or others: I think you should post the counterexamples as an answer